# Markdown for checkboxes

Tags: feature-request, markdown, markdown-rendering

I found on GitHub that you can use Markdown like this:

- [X] Completed feature
- [ ] Incompleted feature

To do checkboxes like this:

[image: Checkboxes]

Comment: WHY IS MARKDOWN NOT A STANDARD? How often do you need a checkbox in your question (or answer)?

Comment: Because GitHub added more features to Markdown that are not part of the [original specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)? It's called GitHub Extended Markdown for a reason.

Comment: [X] Need checkboxes

Comment: ☑️ Emoji to the rescue.

Comment: @bobobobo: You haven't explained *why* we "Need checkboxes". GitHub actually ties them into specific features of issue lists and the like. How would they be tied into features here?

Comment: Perhaps [posts to do with things you're planning to do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) and come back to edit the post to indicate what's been done so far.

Comment: @bobobobo: If you're talking about Docs.SO stuff, then that should be something that's handled by the discussion section or by a request, not by some random checkbox. It also suggests that the example in question is getting too large if you have to post it in bits.

Comment: This is not even a question.
And it answer itself already.

Answer (score 19):

GitHub has extended the [original Markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/); they added checkboxes, tables, code block fences (```` ``` ```` markers) and a few other features. Those are not part of the base specification, and thus are not supported in other Markdown implementations such as the one used on Stack Overflow.

I see no need whatsoever for checkboxes in questions and answers. We are not building TODO lists here.

Comment: TODO: Mark as status declined

Comment: You know why I cannot accept this answer