# List of topics with LINKED articles - most voted articles can help users to learn - SEPARATE counter of points for articles & answered questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Currently, on this site only those who provide the best answers to specific questions get points/credits. That is super cool. It helps greatly when you need clarification of certain small matter.

However, those who write most influential articles do not get Stack Overflow points/credits. And best articles are not voted/rated so that new learners could easily find best articles in certain topics. Currently, the best friend of new learners (when they need comprehensive explanation on a topic, not answer to specific part of a topic) is Google. But you need to have some luck to find the best article.

So CAN WE HAVE THIS: the current question/answer flow works super fine. Can Stack Overflow have this as one totally separate branch and concurrently, have another, fully independent branch, as preparing a list of major topics across platforms and/or main concepts (like OOP) and for which people would suggest best articles WRITTEN NOT ON THIS SITE, BUT ON OTHER SITES indicating authors name and when people upvote authors of the article would get points/credits (I do not know if those who added link should get points as well). The best way would be if authors add their articles themselves to achieve accuracy in defining the author's identity.

Then Stack Overflow could suggest to authors of those article Stack Overflow 's code snippet that enables to upvote those articles directly from the site in which an article is published (the same way we can press Facebook's Like button on any website).

This would help the most influential writers to get points/credits they deserve and motivate others to write best articles to gain/earn Stack Overflow's points/credits.

It would also help new learners to have on Stack Overflow's website a REPOSITORY OF TITLES AND LINKS TO ARTICLES WRITTEN IN OTHER WEB-SITES (e.g. drop down list by topics with links to articles) of most-voted articles.

With NO CHANGE TO CURRENT SETUP of the site it could be A PARELLEL and totally independent part of the site.

This way, a particular person, who answers others' questions and who writes articles at the same time, would be able to have additional, separate counter of points/credits and together with points earned for answering questions it would show his/her overall proficiency level.

POINTS / CREDITS VOTED FOR ARTICLES WOULD BE COUNTED AND DISPLAYED TOTALLY SEPARATELY FROM POINTS / CREDITS EARNED FOR ANSWERING QUESTIONS - THERE WOULD BE TWO SCORES - FOR ANSWERING QUESTIONS AND FOR ARTICLES.

EDIT: Or, if users of this site do not like this to be part of this site, then someone else could do this ( rating of articles by topics ) in another web-site not related to this web-site.

My point is that, as far as I know, there is:
- no well-known site or other service or resource where articles, written on the same topic, are rated (to enable to select the best ones among them), and;
- no points-based system for rewarding the best article writers which would motivate them to write more similar articles.

(Sorry if something similar exits or has been discussed.)

Comment: Something like this (supporting writing articles rather than Q&A) was tried with [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow). It didn't work out, though. Expanding the reputation system to external resources would be so fraught with difficulties it would probably be impossible to do.

Comment: What is "OOO"? Do you mean "[OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)"?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Yes, it should be OOP, it is a typo. I changed it to OOP.

Comment: There already are places where people can submit articles, and other people can vote and comment on the submissions: [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) and the [/r/programming](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/) subreddit come to mind. Authors don't get "points", though, unless they submit the articles themselves.

Answer (score 17):

No.

You get reputation for participating on the site in its current form.  If you don't participate on the site in its current form, you do not get reputation.

Allowing people to just write articles here which aren't germane to the whole Q&A flow of the site isn't going to jive here, and I don't see a reason for that to be rewarded.

<sup>I know that Documentation existed to kind of allow for more free-form guidance and guidelines, but until that project really figures out what it wants to be (or if it'll come back at all), users are expected to participate through questions and answers.</sup>