# Why not have a tutorials feature on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While there is no doubt that SO is great at uncovering problems and providing answers to specific needs and issues, many times general questions like "How do I do X" gets voted down, simply because a programmer may have no idea what specific question to ask.

I am wondering whether a feature that would allow people to develop end-to-end tutorials, much like that on *[The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project)* , would be worthwhile. The Stack Overflow feature would be different in as much as users could edit the tutorial and enhance it.

For example, I recently had to set up XDEBUG on a Windows server. While I eventually got it working, the information was all over the place and it was like piecing together a puzzle - if having learnt a fair bit it would be good to be able to put something up onto SO without asking a [Dorothy Dixer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothy_Dixer) question.

Comment: Sounds not too far from https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/

Comment: How exactly would this work? As far as I can tell, the proposal is just that this *should exist* but not how it would relate to anything else on [SO]. So far, [open ended or unfocused question are explicitly "not a good fit for this site"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) so providing a solid reason for such a U-turn seems prudent. Many things are good to have, that does not mean they are a good have *on Stack Overflow*.

Comment: "if having learnt a fair bit it would be good to be able to put something up onto SO without asking a Dorothy Dixer question." I'm not too familiar with Australian politics, but wouldn't that amount to self-answered questions? Those are [explicitly allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: [The company has indicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwpFzAR4FX4&t=25m10s) they want to do something like this (my emphasis): *"New types of content: Articles,* ***courses,*** *blogs, and challenges"*

Comment: Thanks MisterMiyagi - Fair enough.  I wasn't aware that Self Answered Question were explicitly allowed.  I had seen them but assume they were cloaked in subterfuge :-)

Comment: Peter, I am not sure blogs and articles are the right way, hence my suggestion.   Real code is far more educational with peoples views of how something works and others adding better ways of doing it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That's nice, although from my observations of their performance so far, I'd say they can barely manage the Q&A part, let alone anything else (that won't be a massive fail within a year). Frankly, I prefer the idea of "Do one thing well, rather than many things poorly." And there's still a long long way to get the Q&A part right -- in fact I'd say that for quite some time it's headed in the opposite direction.

Comment: I mean... a lot of the articles that have been posted so far in collectives seem to be trying to be tutorials. Have they been useful for anything?

Comment: And all of us, would have at some stage gone to a tutorial or book to find the starting point - we take the starting point (tutorial or book example) to prove a concept and then through iteration build the application out and as we run into problems we invoke Stackoverflow to help us solve the issue we have uncovered.   All I am saying is that there could be scope for a holistic approach.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, and the documentation project was a **good idea** that the community was not ready for and didn't properly understand.

Answer (score 16):

Stack Overflow (and really, the whole exchange) is built around Q&A.  There was a branching out attempt with [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/1079354), but it was immediately bit by the fact that people would just...write the kind of documentation you could just Google *anyway*, and get reputation for doing so, leaving the more niche stuff to not encourage much engagement, which led to lower incentives to do it, and meant that Documentation *only* ever focused on the easier stuff.

Besides, these days, dev.to already has this feature.  Sure, it's not going to be as prominent as Stack Overflow, but it's a more flexible format to allow for it at all.

Comment: Yes, I get that - but I am suggesting that Q&A be built into the example somehow.  At the moment the comments in the Q&A serve some of the purpose but are all over the place and certainly not coherent. Maybe it is more like a wiki code page where certain concepts are explained  through call outs in the code, say a perfect example of a closure in context etc.

Comment: Some of the tag wikis (take [Java for example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)) include a lot of this sort of thing already.  It's just not visible enough since getting tutorials is orthogonal to the goal of *many* askers just looking for someone to solve their problem.  But again, this doesn't actually solve the main problem or limitation - people have and will continue to submit "easy" things to do tutorials on and the more complex things will remain unaddressed, which undermines the value of having such a feature in the first place.

Comment: I can't argue with that, but I do wonder as to how something like this idea would have evolved and maybe could have turned out to be surprisingly useful.  But with all the down-votes it is unlikely to happen!

Comment: @Alexander it's probably more likely to happen than you might think. SO (the company) has been doing a lot of research into the "teaching" side of things as opposed to being a knowledgebase.

Answer (score -1):

> For example, I recently had to set up XDEBUG on a Windows server. While I eventually got it working, the information was all over the place and it was like piecing together a puzzle - if having learnt a fair bit it would be good to be able to put something up onto SO without asking a Dorothy Dixer question.

Now that you've figured it out, take stock of the situation.

What were the steps you had to follow?

Would *everyone* else setting up XDEBUG need to follow *all the same* steps? Why or why not?

Was the sticking point actually in figuring out all the steps? Or was it in implementing one or more of the individual steps?

If individual steps were difficult - [what did the process look like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) for finding the "information" that was "all over the place"? Did you get clear answers for individual steps, or were they merely implied by documentation? Consequently - could you write a "Dorothy Dixer question" for the step, and answer it, and *thereby provide value that isn't readily available* with a search engine?

If you can, and it doesn't already exist on Stack Overflow, then **ask and answer it**. This is [allowed and explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and is commonly the source of the best quality content the site has to offer. Many of the most important reference questions in the Python tag [are like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503), and a lot of the others have been edited over the years to look that way - since the person originally asking, as you describe, didn't know what to ask.

If the problem is in figuring out the steps, but the list of steps

- is clear and leaves no real room for customization;
- isn't properly explained in documentation;
- isn't addressed by existing questions

then a proper Stack Overflow question can likely be made out of that, too. But keep in mind that a question here needs to be **focused**.

Comment: This doesn't really address the root of the question...this is just trying to fit the square peg of wanting a tutorial into the triangular hole of Stack Exchange's brand of Q&A.  Your advice would be useful if someone were trying to *convert* their tutorial into a Q&A-style question, with caveats to a few things being missed for it.

Comment: ... Is that somehow not an expected and appropriate way, on Meta, to respond to an unpopular feature request?